# Full wave active rectification for lower voltages?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, rectifier, bridge-rectifier, full-bridge

I have been following these youtube tutorials on active rectification to learn more about the topic.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VR456CsHYx4

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=arvNukW-jeo

I simulated the final full wave active rectification circuit, in ltspice, with 4 mosfets and a mosfet driven by an op amp to prevent reverse current. However I am noticing that this design starts to fail for lower AC amplitudes.

35V active rectification:

Edit:  Improved diagram from Audioguru

[image]

[image]

Take for example when the input voltage amplitude is 10V instead of 35V.
there is a larger voltage drop and (some) distortion on the waveform.
Why is this? Is Full wave active rectification for lower voltages achievable?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Threshold voltage.

M2 and M4 do not begin to conduct until Vgs exceeds the FETs threshold voltage.  This is the minimum gate-source voltage required for conduction at current levels greater than leakage.  It is specified on the datasheet and can be determined from the charts.  There usually is a plot of Vgs versus Rds.

In your 35 V case it is too small to see, but it always is there.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/uiC4O93
I believe this is the chart you are referring to. However the difference between Vgs=10V and Vgs=35 is a couple of milliohms, is that enough for a voltage drop of 0.5V ?

Comment: Do you check Vdio? Stabilizer circuit looks strange and fail-prone to startup.
If the source is a transformer output, it may be possible to wind another coil with higher voltage for gate control.

Comment: @Vladimir Vdio looks fine, https://imgur.com/a/WzShy4B It could be that but I am not sure why, is that what the op-amp feedback circuit portion is called? a stabilizer circuit? It could be VGS on M3 not reaching a high enough threshold.

Comment: Purpose of U1 and M3 is unclear for me and it may be designed wrong. I thought that it should be voltage stabilizer. Power supply of opamp is discontinuous and negative input's potential is floating somewhere (?)

Comment: @Vladimir The idea is for U2 to drive M3 by measuring the voltage before and after M3 and when the input is larger than the output the transistor be on.

Comment: Then, IMO is better to use comparator and two voltage dividers, from Vin and Vout, going to +in and -in of comp. It's power should has capacitor and zener to ground.